# Find Java options used by Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, jvm-arguments, java-opts

How can I find which Java options (Xmx, Xms, Xss, etc) are being used by Maven?

I've found out that a way to **set** them is via the environment MAVEN_OPTS. Now I want a way to be assured it's getting the right settings.

EDIT: I believe it´s different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167364/how-to-print-the-actual-maven-options-that-are-being-used) as I don´t want to see the value of an environment variable. I rather want to see which settings are actually being used by Maven, whether it comes from a env var, settings.xml or other means.

EDIT2: I'm also interested in other ways of setting Java options for a Maven build

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the actual MAVEN\_OPTIONS that are being used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167364/how-to-print-the-actual-maven-options-that-are-being-used)

Comment: Are you only interested in seeing how to check which options Maven used or also in other ways of settings the same options?

Comment: yes I´m also interested on other ways, thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, check at its bottom, I found a way to get check whether the option was picked up correctly. Hope that can help

Comment: Moreover, you probably want it from Java, which is invoked by Maven (being developed in Java), so [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486375/print-all-jvm-flags) in combination with the approach I proposed should give you further help. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: and the jinfo command could also come to hand, as described by this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231393/how-do-i-know-which-default-settings-are-enabled-for-sun-jvm)

Answer (score 17):

You can set Java options for Maven in different points and level (globally or via plugins configuration):

**Plugin configuration: just for Compilation**
Using the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) configuration for compiling application code and test code, you can set the required Xmx, Xms, Xss options via the `compileArgs` configuration entry, available for both [compile](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) and [testCompile](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html) goals. An official example is available [here](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html) and on other SO answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035389/how-to-set-xxpermsize-64m-in-maven-compiler-plugin).
An example is also shown below on the third point.

**Plugin configuration: just for Tests execution**
Using the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin) configuration for tests executions, you can set the required Java options to be used at runtime via the `argLine` configuration entry of the [test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) goal. An official example is available [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html).
An example is also shown below on the third point.

**Plugin configuration: via Properties (and profiles)**
You can combine the two options above (in case of common Java options) as a property value to pass to both `compileArgs` and `argLine` configuration entry or have different properties per configuration (according to your needs).

```
<property>
      <jvm.options>-Xmx256M</jvm.options>
</property>

[...]
<build>
  [...]
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.3</version>
       <compilerArgs>
            <arg>${jvm.options}</arg>
       </compilerArgs>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
       <configuration>
            <argLine>${jvm.options}</argLine>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
   [...]
</build>
[...]
```

Using properties gives you also an two extra advantages (on top of centralization): you can use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) then to personalize it based on different desired behaviours (and example in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829538/maven-surefire-append-to-argline)) and you  can override them via command line as well, like:

```
mvn clean install -Djvm.options=-Xmx512
```

**Global/Project configuration: Options file**
Since Maven 3.3.1, you can [specify](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5767) your options in a `.mvn/jvm.config` file per project. It's an alternative to MAVEN_OPTS and a more narrowed scope (per project). However, since it sis a new Maven feature, people should be aware of it, otherwise troubleshooting and maintenance may be impacted.

**Global/Env configuration: MAVEN_OPTS**
Maven [well-known](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) environment variable to set global execution options, however applied to all Maven builds sharing that environment (i.e. per logged user).

When running Maven using the `-X` option (debug enabled), you will have the following output as part of your build:

```
[DEBUG] properties used {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, ... , env.MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx256M, ...
```

---

**Update**
After all, the executed `mvn` command is an OS script. Having a look at it in Windows, I found the possibility of using the `MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO` option which, if enabled (value set to `on`), will echo any command executed by the script and as such also the invocation of the `java` command, where you can see if your options (the `MAVEN_OPTS`) are picked up correctly together with the full list of parameters passed to it.

Here is an execution I tested on Windows:

```
set MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO=on
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx256M
mvn compile > output.txt
```

NOTE: the `output.txt` will contain quite a lot of text, providing build output and additional `echo`s executions. As part of it, it provided:

```
>"path_to_\jdk1.7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx256M -classpath "path_to\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar" "-Dclassworlds.conf=path_to\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=path_to\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\.." org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher compile
```

As you can see, the `-Xmx256M` option was picked up correctly. If the maven script for other OS doesn't provide this option, then you can simply add it to the script (a simple `echo` before the `java` execution, showing the command, would also be enough).
You can find the maven script in your maven installation folder, under the `bin` subfolder.

---

**Update2**
Furthermore, since Maven is a Java tool after all and as you can see from its script it invokes the java command, you could see all the available options as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486375/print-all-jvm-flags) by slightly changing the Maven script and use the `jinfo` command  which should really give you the answer according to this other [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231393/how-do-i-know-which-default-settings-are-enabled-for-sun-jvm).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to start Maven with verbose debug output (-debug, I think?). Otherwise just do a `ps aux | grep java` and check the arguments of the process (assuming *nix).