# Getting OutOfMemoryException :Permgern space issue in jenkins

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, heap-dump

I am getting **OutOfMemoryExeption:Permgern space** issue when building a Maven project in Jenkins.
At the end of the building process message is showing as "Build Success" .But after that line below error msg is printing.
           **Fatal Error : Permgern space** 
Once this exception comes ,every time whole Jenkins is getting hanged i.e no 
corresponding page of Jenkins even if dash board is not opening.

Below is the Command Line argument error for Jenkins.
          Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM Warning : Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 
occured dispatching signal unknown to handler - The VM may need to forcibly terminated.

Below is the error details from the console O/P of job-

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building EmployeeInformation 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
**[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.161 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-11T00:55:52+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/76M**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 49708
[Employee_Management] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03/bin/java" -cp "C:\Users\pc\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-agent-1.7.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main "C:\Program Files\Apache\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9" C:\Users\pc\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.62.jar C:\Users\pc\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar C:\Users\pc\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-**commons-1.7.jar 49708
FATAL: PermGen space
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
FATAL: PermGen space**
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.main(Maven32Main.java:144)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.main(Maven32Main.java:74)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:365)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:310)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:530)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:513)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:504)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:500)
    ... 6 more
```

Below are some of the possible steps I tried to solve-
    (1)In POM.XML below tag added.
                [attached image link for Changed permgern space configuration in POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M31Qx.png)
    (2)Set JAVA_OPTS in enviroment variable.
                [attached image link for setting enviromental variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M309h.png)

But,unfortunately none of them  working.Still issue is there.
After searching some where,I got to know 
             **-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m** declaration will resolve the issue.But I am not sure **Where and How** to give the above declaration.

Guys,Plz go through the above links I attached and let me know If any thing I did wrong.
Any help will be appreciated.

BR//
Abinash

Comment: if its possibile to update to hava 8, you should do that - there is no "PermGen limit"

Answer (score 1):

Add your options to the **`_JAVA_OPTIONS`** environment variable -- this will work for sure.

Otherwise, for customizing the compiler options in your Maven build environment, there's several possibilities. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739321/find-java-options-used-by-maven) for an overview.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. +1 for providing a better answer!